# Save 20 users with one SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

i save a user like this in doctrine:

```
$user = User();
$user->name = 'peter';
$user->save();
```

is there a way to save 20 users in one sql query?

or do i have to loop the above code 20 times hence creating 20 sql queries?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may add your `$user` objects to [Doctrine_Collection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Collection/1_2) and then call `$collection->save()`, which basically does the loop for you.

Answer (score 2):

From your point of view as a Doctrine user, you are working with objects, and should not be concerned by SQL queries.

If you have 20 different users, then, you should have 20 different objects -- which means, yes, 20 queries *(or more, depending on what your objects are doing)* to save them.